# Pass function from one screen to another in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Im trying to pass a function `handleNewFavourite` (which updates my `favouriteList` state array) from my `HomeScreen` to my `DetailsScreen` via navigation params but Im getting the following error: `Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state`

How should I pass functions that modified the state between different stack screens?

HomeScreen code:

```js
<FlatList
        data={checkCategory()}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate('Details', {
                item,
                handleNewFavourite,
              })
            }>
            <LessonCard lesson={item} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
/>
```

DetailScreen code:

```js
const LessonDetails = ({lesson, handleNewFavourite}: LessonProps) => {
  const [favourite, setFavourite] = useState<boolean>(lesson.favourite);
  return (
    <LessonDetailsContainer>
      <LessonDetailsInfoContainer>
        <LessonDetailsCategoryHead>
          <LessonDetailsCategory>{lesson.category}</LessonDetailsCategory>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setFavourite(!favourite);
              handleNewFavourite(lesson);
            }}>
            <LessonDetailsFavouriteIcon>
              {favourite ? '❤️' : ''}
            </LessonDetailsFavouriteIcon>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </LessonDetailsCategoryHead>
        <LessonDetailsTitle>{lesson.title}</LessonDetailsTitle>
        <LessonDetailsAuthor>{lesson?.author}</LessonDetailsAuthor>
      </LessonDetailsInfoContainer>
      <LessonDetailsCardImage
        source={{
          uri: lesson.image,
        }}
      />
      <LessonDetailsContentContainer>
        <LessonDetailsDescriptionText>
          {lesson.content}
        </LessonDetailsDescriptionText>
      </LessonDetailsContentContainer>
    </LessonDetailsContainer>
  );
};

export default LessonDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

For situation like this, you should learn global state management. ( Context API - Redux etc. )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are disrupting in the wrong way the parameters passed to `DetailScreen` it should be something like this:

```
const LessonDetails = ({route}: LessonProps) => {
      const {lesson, handleNewFavourite} = route.params;
// The rest of your component here
}
```

As the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params) suggested. But as @omerfarukose mentioned is not a bad idea to use state management in this particular scenario